# Wordpress subdomains Multisite gives a 404 error only on one subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, shared-hosting, multisite

Looking forward y'all have an excellent day

I'm having a kind of strange issue, I'm developing a Wordpress multisite with subdomains and I have no issue with creating new sites in every but one subdomain and I can't figure out why.

My wordpress installation is on here: evoco.io and for some reason when I create the new site "marketing.evoco.io" it wont work:
[image: Wordpress multisite added sites]

[image: 404 error on marketing.evoco.io]

It shows a 404 page from TMD Hosting. I tried checking the files to see if there was a marketing.evoco.io subdirectory that might be causing the issue but this was not the case. Also checked on Cloudflare if there was any issue with the DNS, maybe an A record that might be causing an issue but everything is ok there, there is a wildcard domain on cloudflare, I have no idea what else I should look into to make marketing.evoco.io work.

[image: Cloudflare DNS config]

[image: No marketing.evoco.io subdomain on server files]

My .htaccess has the following configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And my wp-config.php has the following configuration:

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'evoco.io' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

What am I missing that is causing specifically marketing.evoco.io not to work but every other site that I add to work perfectly fine?

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: That subdomain appears to be working OK for me (200 OK response): "Welcome to Evoco. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!". Maybe a localised DNS/caching issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, there was a problem with my Hosting Provider where the domain wasn't completely deleted on cpanel even though it wasn't showing up on the GUI. Everything is working fine now! :)